# Hyperlink on a Picture

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I have a picture with a hyperlink, however, when I download the picture to Facebook the hyperlink does not work.  Can you not put a hyperlink on a picture?  I would like it if people open the picture, they will be able to click on the picture and it take them to a website.

Comment: Do you mean when you regularly upload a photo to facebook, or when you share a picture that's in link, or something else entirely? If either of those first too - it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to wrap the image with an  pointing it to the site where your sharing it on. However, if your using FaceBook to host the image, then you'll be using the API of FaceBook and won't have control over what happens when a user clicks on the image. Maybe just share the link in the description??